# "internal logic error" after upgrading from Xcode 3 to Xcode 4.2

Tags: macos, xcode

I've just upgraded to Xcode 4.2 a few days ago from Xcode 3. The project I have been working on seemed to get on well to 4.2 with no problem at all for the first few days. But then after I moved a layer on the IB slightly by mistake (but I adjusted it back), Xcode 4.2 started having this "internal logic error" thing.

I tried to copy from a backup of my source code to the working folder. The "internal logic error" went away but the project is behaving strangely.

- First, a layer does not position as it used to be.
- Then, there are strange compile errors that it didn't have.

Wonder if anyone has encountered anything similar. Do I need to install Xcode 4.2 from my download again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I have found the answer myself.  Those of you who are new to Xcode just as I am, do not panic as I did.  Just perform a product - clean (from menu) and everything should be ok ...